# Very slow query to find all records without a relationship

Tags: mysql, left-join, relationship, not-exists

I am trying to find all of the `users` which do **not** have any `orders`.

So far I've tried the following:

```
select * from `users` where not exists 
(select * from `orders` where `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
select users.*, count(distinct orders.reference) as orders_count from `users` 
left join `orders` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` 
group by `users`.`id` having orders_count = 0
```

However, both are very slow running queries. There are around 5000 customers and 30,000+ orders. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Did you tried indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit your subquery to only look at user_id. Also make sure user_id is indexed.

```
Alter table orders add index(user_id)

Select * from users where id NOT IN(select user_id from 
orders)
```